# jQuery Validation Issue - I want to validate a field for these constraints :-

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

Please help me in writing the regular expression for the constraints as follows :-

1. First letter should not be blank
2. Permissible characters are alphabets and numbers
3. Apart from numbers and characters, two more characters are allowed which are - and /
4. Last character cannot be blank

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It asks the responders to write code

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^/^[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9\/-]*[A-Z0-9]$/i
```

Though it isn't clear what you mean by `blank`. Space isn't even allowed in your character set.